# CSV File header part is coming parsing by LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, csv

the below way i am parsing csv file by LINQ but i found header part is coming when i inspect user class data. what is wrong there in code.

```
    var csvlines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);   // IEnumerable<string>
    var csvLinesData = csvlines.Select(l => l.Split(',').Skip(1).ToArray());  // IEnumerable<string[]>
    int flag = 0;
    var users = csvLinesData.Select(data => new User
    {
        CSRName = data[6],
        CallStart = data[0],
        CallDuration = data[1],
        RingDuration = data[2],
        Direction = data[3],
        IsInternal = data[4],
        Continuation = data[5],
        ParkTime = data[7]
    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be doing the `Skip(1)` in the wrong place:

```
var csvLinesData = csvlines.Skip(1).Select(l => l.Split(',').ToArray());  // IEnumerable<string[]>
```

As it stands you're skipping the first *column* for each row, not the first *row*.

Comment: `l.Split(',').ToArray()` is now redundant since `Split` already returns an array.

Comment: @TimSchmelter true, but it's not hurting anything and better illustrates what the actual problem is.

Comment: It doubles the memory consumption for a short period, it's also not related to the problem, is it?

Answer (score 1):

You are skipping the first column, not the first row, use this instead:

```
csvlines.Skip(1).Select(l => l.Split(','));
```

note that it doesn't matter if the `Skip` comes before or behind the `Select`, you could also write:

```
csvlines.Select(l => l.Split(',')).Skip(1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of skipping the first column of every line, skip the first line instead. That is, move the `Skip(1)` ahead of the `Select()`. Like so:

```
var csvlines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);   // IEnumerable<string>

//var csvLinesData = csvlines.Select(l => l.Split(',').Skip(1).ToArray());  // IEnumerable<string[]>    
// Instead of skipping the first column, skip the first line!
var csvLinesData = csvlines.Skip(1).Select(l => l.Split(',').ToArray());  // IEnumerable<string[]>

int flag = 0;
var users = csvLinesData.Select(data => new User
{
    CSRName = data[6],
    CallStart = data[0],
    CallDuration = data[1],
    RingDuration = data[2],
    Direction = data[3],
    IsInternal = data[4],
    Continuation = data[5],
    ParkTime = data[7]
}).ToList();
```